# Three capacitors in a loop and dependence?

Tags: capacitor

I was watching a lecture on State Variables on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d34nosv-_uc)

The professor mentioned that "if three capacitors form a loop, the three cannot be independently specified. Only two can be done as the third becomes dependent on the other two". I was wondering how the two capacitors and can independent and the third dependent?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you tell us what time he says that so we can get a better context? It is a 53 minute video after all.

Comment: It's around the 40 minute mark. When I get home from work, I can give you the exact time the professor talks about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three caps in series across a "10V" power supply. If one cap (C1) has 2V across it and another (C2) has 5 volts across it, the third HAS to have 3 volts across it because: -

2 + 5 + 3 =10

If the power supply was 0V it makes no difference: -

C1 has (say) 2V across it, C2 has 5V across it and the third must have -7V across it because

2 + 5 - 7 = 0

Comment: Looks suspiciously much like [Kirchhoff's Voltage Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff.27s_voltage_law_.28KVL.29) ;o)

Comment: @jippie describe first, let the dude take it on board then give it a name LOL

Comment: @Andyaka I think the author is referring to the capacitance of, not that voltage across each. That's how I remember it from school at any rate.